# Incorrect output of index on list elements - Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I just started to study Python and I am stuck at this one.

basically I would like to find out the add numbers in the odd index number.

here is my code.

```
def odd_ones(lst):
    total = []
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            total.append(i)
    return total

print(odd_ones([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

Output is

`[1, 3, 5, 7]` instead of `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `for i in lst` is iterating over the _elements_, not the _indices_. You need `for i, x in enumerate(lst): if i % 2 == 1: total.append(x)`

Comment: `for i in range(len(lst))` would be enough.

Comment: @Taegyung except then you have to index into `lst` and `for i in range(len(lst)): # anything with lst[i]` is a huge code smell.

Comment: @AdamSmith then writing `for i, _` would be bad practice. Wait... I think you edited?  `for i, x in enumerate(lst)` looks good enough. If that was what you wrote in the first place, my apologies.

Comment: your output will be [0, 2, 4, 6] not [2, 4, 6, 8]

Comment: @Taegyung I edited. `for i, _ in enumerate(lst)` is preferred to `for i in range(lst)` if you don't need the elements (imo). It's a bit more clear what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The output is correct. You iterate over the list of values and not its indices. Condition `i % 2 == 1` gives following:

```
1 % 2 = 1 (true)
2 % 2 = 0 (false)
3 % 2 = 1 (true)
4 % 2 = 0 (false)
5 % 2 = 1 (true)
6 % 2 = 0 (false)
7 % 2 = 1 (true)
8 % 2 = 0 (false)
```

So the output is `(1,3,5,7)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the odd inedx ,but what you really do is to find the odd element

```
for i in lst:  #(i ---->the element in lst)   
    if i % 2 == 1:
```

so you should try this

```
for i in range(len(lst)): #( i ---> the index of lst)
    if i % 2 == 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

as required  `odd index number`, `enumerate` provides counter/index

```
def odd_ones_index(lst):
    total = []
    for x,i in enumerate(lst):
        if i % 2 == 1: ## checking i is odd or not
            total.append(x) ## appending index as you want index

    return total
print(odd_ones_index([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wont to get the odd number into your array you need to change your condition, so the code most be like that:

```
def odd_ones(lst):
    total = []
    for i in lst:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            total.append(i)
    return total

print(odd_ones([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
```

output:[2, 4, 6, 8]